# how to push to, update elements inside an array that is in a object of a react functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component, react-state-management

```
const [Collect, setCollect] = React.useState({
visible: false,
files:[],
uploading: 0,
team:"",
manager:"",
owner:"",
fileNames: [],
status:""
```

});

```
function fileOnChange(e){
// here update files and filenames arrays
}
```

i have a functional component that has an object with arrays as shown above. how can u update the arrays everytime new files selected from the input. the fileOnChange method to update add files and filesnames

Comment: Hi what have you tried? You're basically asking someone to write the whole function for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another variable to store previous filenames and files

```js
let temp1 = Collect.filenames;
let temp2 = Collect.files;
temp1.push('anotherFilename');
temp2.push('anotherFile');
setCollect({...Collect, filenames: temp1, files: temp2});
```

Comment: `temp` is not declared. This also appears to be an incomplete solution. How does a new file and filename get into state?

Comment: i'm using this method now....just want to know if there is a better way without using push. if the arrays are seperate then i can use SetFiles(prevState => [...prevState, newFile]);. i want to know whats the best way

Comment: Yes you can do that.

Comment: If you are using a form then you can also avoid using state variables. You can just retrieve the data on form submission and send it to the server.